# htaccess redirect subdomain to same subdomain with different path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a subdomain path to different path using .htaccess but keep the subdomain and parameter in the url like this:

**Source url**: `http://dev.domain.com/rezept?recipe_id=2513&language=de`

**Target url**: `http://dev.domain.com/recipe/detail?recipe_id=2513&language=de`

I tried the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rezept/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dev.swissveg\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /recipe/detail/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this rule:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dev\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^rezept/?$ recipe/detail [L,NC]
```

Query string will be automatically carried over to the target URI.